# locust Exception: No tasks defined on use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance-testing, locust

Source code is here https://github.com/anishnath/vault-load-testing/blob/master/locusts/key_value.py#L65

To run

`locust --host https://10.1.3.211:8200  --headless`

Hello expert getting error with

```
: No tasks defined on KeyValueLocust. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

Locust Version

`locust 2.8.2`

The code

```py
import json
import sys

import os
import random

from locust import HttpLocust, task
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import common
from locusts import VaultTaskSet, VaultLocust
class KeyValueTasks(VaultTaskSet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.kv_version = 1

    
    def on_start(self):
        self.kv_version = common.get_kv_version(client=self.client)

    @task
    def get_kv_secret(self):
        

    @task
    def put_kv_secret(self):
        

    @task
    def list_l1_secrets(self):
        

    @task
    def list_l2_secrets(self):
        key_path = common.key_path_1()
        


class KeyValueLocust(VaultLocust):
    task_set = KeyValueTasks
    weight = 3
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 10000
```

The locustfile.py

```
from locusts.key_value import KeyValueLocust

__static__ = [KeyValueLocust]
__all__ = __static__
```

The

```py
from locust import TaskSet, HttpUser
from locust.clients import ResponseContextManager, HttpSession, RequestException, CatchResponseError
import time

import os
import json


class VaultLocust(HttpUser):

    token = None
    testdata = None
    abstract = True

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.client = VaultSession(base_url=self.host,request_event=self.client.request_event, user=self)

    def setup(self):
        

    @classmethod
    def _set_token(cls, token):
        cls.token = token

    @classmethod
    def _set_testdata(cls, data):
        cls.testdata = data


class VaultTaskSet(TaskSet):

    def mount(self, name: str, mount_point: str=None):
        mount_point = mount_point or name
        r = self.client.get('/v1/sys/mounts')
        if f'{mount_point}/' not in r.json():
            self.client.post(f'/v1/sys/mounts/{mount_point}', json={'type': name})

    def enable_auth(self, name: str, path: str=None):
        path = path or name
        r = self.client.get('/v1/sys/auth')
        if f'{path}/' not in r.json():
            self.client.post(f'/v1/sys/auth/{path}', json={'type': name})

    def revoke_lease(self, lease_id: str):
        self.client.put('/v1/sys/leases/revoke',
                        json={'lease_id': lease_id})

    def is_in_list(self, key: str, uri: str) -> bool:
        with self.client.request('LIST', uri, catch_response=True) as r:
            if r.status_code == 404:
                r.success()
                return False
            else:
                return key in r.json()['data']['keys']

    @property
    def client(self) -> HttpSession:
        client = super().client  # type: HttpSession
        client.headers['X-Vault-Token'] = self.locust.token
        return client


class VaultSession(HttpSession):

    def request(self, method, url, name=None, catch_response=False, **kwargs):

        # Load any TLS certificates specified in the VAULT_CACERT env var
        self.verify = os.environ.get('VAULT_CACERT', None)

        # prepend url with hostname unless it's already an absolute URL
        url = self._build_url(url)

        # store meta data that is used when reporting the request to locust's statistics
        request_meta = dict()

        # set up pre_request hook for attaching meta data to the request object
        request_meta["method"] = method
        request_meta["start_time"] = time.time()

        response = self._send_request_safe_mode(method, url, **kwargs)

        # record the consumed time
        request_meta["response_time"] = int((time.time() - request_meta["start_time"]) * 1000)

        request_meta["name"] = name or (response.history and response.history[0] or response).request.path_url

        # get the length of the content, but if the argument stream is set to True, we take
        # the size from the content-length header, in order to not trigger fetching of the body
        if kwargs.get("stream", False):
            request_meta["content_size"] = int(response.headers.get("content-length") or 0)
        else:
            request_meta["content_size"] = len(response.content or "")

        if catch_response:
            response.locust_request_meta = request_meta
            return ResponseContextManager(response)
        else:
            try:
                response.raise_for_status()
            except RequestException as e:
                try:
                    e = CatchResponseError('. '.join(response.json()['errors']))
                except KeyError:
                    e = CatchResponseError(e)
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    e = CatchResponseError(e)

                events.request_failure.fire(
                    request_type=request_meta["method"],
                    name=request_meta["name"],
                    response_time=request_meta["response_time"],
                    exception=e,
                )
            else:
                events.request_success.fire(
                    request_type=request_meta["method"],
                    name=request_meta["name"],
                    response_time=request_meta["response_time"],
                    response_length=request_meta["content_size"],
                )
            return response
```

==== UPDATE ====

Tried @cyberwiz approach still got the same error

```py
class KeyValueLocust(VaultLocust):
    task = [KeyValueTasks]
    weight = 3
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 10000
```

```
[2022-02-17 11:16:40,809] AV-MBP-709/ERROR/locust.user.task: No tasks defined on KeyValueLocust. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/PycharmProjects/vault-load-testing2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 304, in run
    self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
  File "/opt/PycharmProjects/vault-load-testing2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 436, in get_next_task
    raise Exception(
Exception: No tasks defined on KeyValueLocust. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User (or mark it as abstract = True if you only intend to subclass it)
```

REPO :  https://github.com/anishnath/vault-load-testing/blob/master/locusts/key_value.py#L65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re setting `task_set` instead of `tasks`.

See http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#id2

Comment: Tried changing that value still got the same error. Can you help ?

Comment: The code repository is here https://github.com/anishnath/vault-load-testing/blob/master/locusts/key_value.py#L65

Comment: "task*s*", not "task"

Comment: can you help here  too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176531/python-locust-throwing-object-has-no-attribute-on-self