# Python locust throwing object has no attribute on self

Tags: python, python-3.x, locust

I'm not able to perform self. and throw with the below error

```
[2022-02-18 15:54:54,527] ip-10-1-172-57.eu-west-1.compute.internal/ERROR/locust.user.task: 'KeyValueTasks' object has no attribute 'locust'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 309, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 334, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(self._task_queue.pop(0))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 346, in execute_task
    task(self)
  File "/home/ec2-user/vault-load-testing/locusts/key_value.py", line 30, in get_kv_secret
    key = random.choice(self.locust.testdata['keys'])
AttributeError: 'KeyValueTasks' object has no attribute 'locust'
```

The source code is here https://github.com/anishnath/vault-load-testing/blob/master/locustfile.py

At first, I initialized the Modules

```py
from locusts.key_value import KeyValueLocust
__static__ = [KeyValueLocust]
__all__ = __static__
```

while accessing the data on `self.locust.testdata['keys']` The error is coming out

https://github.com/anishnath/vault-load-testing/blob/master/locusts/key_value.py#L28

```
@task
def get_kv_secret(self):
    key = random.choice(self.locust.testdata['keys'])
    if self.kv_version == 1:
        self.client.get(f'/v1/secret/test/{key}', name='/v1/secret/[key1]/[key2]')
    else:
        self.client.get(f'/v1/secret/data/test/{key}', name='/v1/secret/[key1]/[key2]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is `self.locust` Supposed to be set? It isn't set anywhere in `KeyValueLocust` that I can find. So the error looks to be correct, you can't call `self.locust` anything because there is no `locust` on `self`.

Perhaps you maybe found some really old examples or documentation for a really old version of Locust that used to have a `locust` attribute in a Task? The current version of Locust doesn't have that. Current documentation for Locust can be found at http://docs.locust.io